# Problem with docker containers communication with port redirection

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So my structure contains 3 apps , 2 servers and 1 client, all in docker containers.

I have no problem communicating with my server containers "manually" (from my UNcontainerized client)

[image: THIS WORKS]

But once my client is containerized I can't communicate with the server with port redirection.

[image: THIS DOESNT WORK]

I get an **Error: connect ECONNREFUSED**

Here is my docker-compose :

```
  client:
    build: ./api-img2txt
    expose:
    - "4000"
    networks:
    - portfolio-network
    container_name: api-img2txt
#####################################################
###################Models############################
#####################################################

  tfserv-1:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    environment:
    - MODEL_NAME=sentimentAnalysis
    ports:
    - "8400:8500"
    - "8401:8501"
    networks:
    - portfolio-network
    container_name: tfserv-1
    volumes:
    - /home/flo/portfolio/api-sentimentAnalysis/sentimentanalysis/model:/models/sentimentAnalysis
    
  tfserv-2:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    environment:
    - MODEL_NAME=lineCounting
    ports:
    - "8500:8500"
    - "8501:8501"
    networks:
    - portfolio-network
    container_name: tfserv-2
    volumes:
    - /home/flo/portfolio/api-img2txt/models/lineCounting:/models/lineCounting 

networks:
  portfolio-network:
```

This is what my client does :

```
import requests

URL = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/lineCounting:predict"
json_request = '{ "instances" : [0] }'
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=json_request)
print('req1',r.json())
print('**********')

URL = "http://localhost:8401/v1/models/sentimentAnalysis:predict"
json_request = '{ "instances" : [0] }'
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=json_request)
print('req2',r.json())
```

I can't change the final port, it must be 8501. How can I make my client communicate with the server on 8401 ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. you are saying port redirections - which is more like port mapping in docker compose.

Secondly - attempt to hep you:

Assuming no magic in `portfolio-network`
and since your client in the same network as both of your servers you should communicate to the through their names but not `localhost`. i.e.

```
URL = "http://tfserv-2:8501/v1/models/lineCounting:predict"
```

and

```
URL = "http://tfserv-1:8401/v1/models/sentimentAnalysis:predict"
```

thus you don't even need to map tfserv-1 to different ports, because you not trying to connect to them from your host PC. docker-compose does names resolutions inside of docker-compose network for you.
i.e. ports are same as in container

```
tfserv-1:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    environment:
    - MODEL_NAME=sentimentAnalysis
    ports:
    - "8500:8500"
    - "8501:8501"
    networks:
    - portfolio-network
    container_name: tfserv-1
    volumes:
    - /home/flo/portfolio/api-sentimentAnalysis/sentimentanalysis/model:/models/sentimentAnalysis
```

and then just do

```
URL = "http://tfserv-1:8501/v1/models/sentimentAnalysis:predict"
```

Meanwhile from you host computer you should be able to go on to `URL = "http://localhost:8401/v1/models/sentimentAnalysis:predict"` with configuration you've provided in the question.

Comment: Puting both servers on 8501:8501 didn't work : `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8501 failed: port is already allocated` . But sending my request to `http://tfserv-1:8501/v1/models/sentimentAnalysis:predict` with mapping 8401:8501 did work , so thank you!